# Why colors is not continuous (layers) in my sample game with lighting?

Tags: graphics, glsl, lighting

I'm testing Sokol library (https://github.com/floooh/sokol) to create a simple game sample with lighting in OpenGL, D3D11 and Metal. I'm using shaders similar from LearnOpenGL tutorials (https://learnopengl.com/Lighting/Light-casters).

This is part of my frag shader:

```
vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - v_position);
float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
diffuse = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0) * diff * vec3(texture(u_diffuse, v_uv));
```

The colors in ground aren't continuous, you can see the color layers (look red lines).

[image: Red light in color layers]

Here is another sample using PBR shaders. Again, color in ground is not continuous.

[image: Red light in color layers again]

Why this happens? How can I create a perfect plane ground?

Answer (score 3):

The "bands" you see just differ by 1 in one of the color channels. You are just reaching the actual limit of 8 bit per channel color precision, there is just no other presentable color in between these two bands. Depending on the display and display settings you use, it will be more or less perceptible.
There are 3 possible solutions:

- The effects are especially visible because your floor is colored in one solid color. The human eye will be most sensitive to such changes (see also [mach band effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_bands)). By adding some structure / texture to it, it won't be perceivable any more.
- Use a display with more then 8 bit per channel of color precision. HDR Displays nowadays do allow 10 or more bits.
- Apply some [dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) to the image to conceal the visible bands. Ordered dithering with some bayer pattern can be easily implemented in a GLSL shader.

Comment: Thanks for help, I understand now. You said to use a display with 10 or more bit per chanel, but do I need also change framebuffer color property? From RGB8 to something like RGB16?

Comment: Well, that is a rather complicate topic. Enabling HDR output usually requires some platform-specific (and maybe even driver specific) APIs, and typically, you have to use a floating point format for your window's framebuffer, the driver will convert it down to the actual precision for the specific display in use. Look for example at [this nvidia presentation](https://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2017/presentation/s7394-tom-true-programming-for-high-dynamic-range.pdf)